# how to ask an integer from the user 3 times with try catch block

Tags: java, arrays, try-catch

the user has to enter 3 integers into a list. im trying to make a try catch block to filer out if the user inputs anything other than an integer.

i inserted the try catch block inside the for loop, the problem is even if the input is not an integer my code scans it and only prints the "enter an integer:" 3 times. how to fix that?

```
THIS IS MY CODE


for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            try{
                //some code
            }catch(Exception e){}
        }
```

i would like the code to go like this:

if the user enters an integer, they only need to input 2 integers
if the user enters a character, the code will prompt an error and will loop back to ask for an integer (2 integers only because the user already entered 1 integer)

```
enter an integer: 1
enter an integer: z

the input is invalid, please try again.

enter an integer: 2
enter an integer: ac

the input is invalid, please try again.

enter an integer: 3
```

Comment: Do `i--;` in your catch block when you tell the user to enter a number again.

Comment: For starters, you shouldn't have a loop that is "pre-set" to go 3 times, because if the wrong information is input you will need to do more iterations.

Comment: Create a counter variable, as suggested by @Alexandr below.
Use a while loop to iterate until you have 3 valid replies. I mean, you could do this in many ways, but something like this is what I would probably do. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to move the

```
System.out.println("done! thank you.");
```

into the try block like that

```
for(int i = 0; i<3; i++){
            try{
                System.out.print("Enter an integer:");
                user_input[i] = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("done! thank you.");
            }catch(InputMismatchException e){
                System.out.println("the input is invalid, please try again");
                input.next();
            }
        }
```

Finally block tries to execute always - no matter how the execution was interrupted. And if you want the user to repeat the the entry, than go i--; in the catch block.

Comment: can you please explain how does the ```input.next();``` work in the catch block?

Answer (score 2):

you can make use of a counter variable, to count valid inputs.

Comment: Yes, and e.g. use a while-loop that will repeat until the count of valid inputs is = 3